# Removing Single Points from a sensor_msgs::PointCloud2

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to build a dynamic mask for robot systems using a Kinect2. My Idea is to use a naive euklidean distance search to remove the robot from the world. (I want to have a hole in the cloud where the robot is)

Unfortunately I don't know how to do that. Can you help me?

This is the part that needs help:

```
for (sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstIterator<float> it(output, "x"); it != it.end(); ++it) {
    // TODO: do something with the values of x, y, z


    try {
        transformStamped = tfBuffer.lookupTransform("kinect2_rgb_optical_frame", "RobotCenter",ros::Time(0),
                                                    ros::Duration(2));

        CamRobX = transformStamped.transform.translation.x;
        CamRobY = transformStamped.transform.translation.y;
        CamRobZ = transformStamped.transform.translation.z;
        CamPointX = it[0];
        CamPointY = it[1];
        CamPointZ = it[2];

        distance = sqrt(pow((CamPointX - CamRobX), 2) + pow((CamPointY - CamRobY), 2) + pow((CamPointZ - CamRobZ), 2));

    }
    catch (tf2::TransformException &ex) {
        ROS_WARN("%s", ex.what());
        ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
        continue;
    }

    // distance refers to a radius of a frame in the middle of the room everything around this frame has to dissapear

    if(distance <0.4){
     
    }

    else{
    }
}

pub.publish(output);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316224/removing-single-points-from-a-sensor_msgs::pointcloud2/) by [Arthur_Ace](https://answers.ros.org/users/39923/arthur_ace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-20**:
Do you absolutely want to solve/implement this yourself, or would a pkg/plugin that does this also be ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given you're written the majority of the code for this it's only a tiny bit of work to get this working. Just to give a bit of background, there are two different types of point cloud that can be represented by PCL: Dense structured point clouds and sparse point clouds.

In dense point clouds, the points are stored in a grid structure a NxM matrix of 3D points with invalid points being represented as vectors of NANs. These types of point clouds are generally created by depth cameras and stereo vision algorithms.

In sparse point clouds, the points are represented as a flat list of points in no specific order these are more commonly generated by LIDAR sensors.

Getting back to your question, the kinect produces dense structured point clouds so you will be able to 'remove' a point by simply setting its x, y and z values to NAN. This means that the grid structure of the points is preserved.

Hope this helps.

**Update**

You can set the values of a point using the iterator you are using in your loop as shown below:

```
it[0] = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
it[1] = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
it[2] = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
```

The iterator functions like a pointer to the pcl::Point allowing you to get and set its values.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arthur_Ace](https://answers.ros.org/users/39923/arthur_ace/) on 2019-02-21**:
That clears things up, thank you! Unfortunately I don't know how and where to set the NAN-Value
also, this is already a sensor_msgs_PointCloud2. Can I do the same here?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-21**:
Yes this should work. I've updated my answer with an example for you now.

**Comment by [Arthur_Ace](https://answers.ros.org/users/39923/arthur_ace/) on 2019-02-21**:
I tried that, but when I try to compile (catkin_make) the following error code appears.
it seems like the iterator won't let me override the values for some reason although it should...

**Comment by [Arthur_Ace](https://answers.ros.org/users/39923/arthur_ace/) on 2019-02-21**:
error: assignment of read-only location ‘it.sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstIterator::.sensor_msgs::impl::PointCloud2IteratorBase<float, const float, const unsigned char, const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_std::allocator<void >, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstIterator>::operator’

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-21**:\

> the iterator won't let me override the values for some reason although it should...

no, it shouldn't. It's a `ConstIterator` ..

**Comment by [Arthur_Ace](https://answers.ros.org/users/39923/arthur_ace/) on 2019-02-21**:
So, how can I circumvent this?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-21**:
Ahh if your working with the message passed to a callback it will be a const (immutable) type. You should be able to create a non-const copy of the message and work on that:

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 newCloud = *cloud_parameter;
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you all for your help! Now I know what I did wrong.
First off: Yes Changing Single Coordinates to NAN works, but like somebody else pointed out, I used the wrong Iterator. Thankfully There was another Iterator which doesn't have the "const" tag in it, and with this one I am able to change points.

Here is the improved code:

```
for (sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Iterator<float> it(output, "x"); it != it.end(); ++it) {
    // TODO: do something with the values of x, y, z


    try {
        transformStamped = tfBuffer.lookupTransform("kinect2_rgb_optical_frame", "RobotCenter",ros::Time(0),
                                                    ros::Duration(2));

        CamRobX = transformStamped.transform.translation.x;
        CamRobY = transformStamped.transform.translation.y;
        CamRobZ = transformStamped.transform.translation.z;
        CamPointX = it[0];
        CamPointY = it[1];
        CamPointZ = it[2];

        distance = sqrt(pow((CamPointX - CamRobX), 2) + pow((CamPointY - CamRobY), 2) + pow((CamPointZ - CamRobZ), 2));

    }
    catch (tf2::TransformException &ex) {
        ROS_WARN("%s", ex.what());
        ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
        continue;
    }
    if(distance <0.4){


        it[0] = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
        it[1] = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
        it[2] = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();


    }

    else{
    }
}

pub.publish(output);
```

---

Originally posted by [Arthur_Ace](https://answers.ros.org/users/39923/arthur_ace/) with karma: 13 on 2019-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1